# Pandas: Splitting a csv file by value in a certain row

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm using ***Pandas*** but I'm very new to it and I would like to know how to split a `.csv` file which looks like this:

```
Code      DateTime      Value
A1        1/1/15 5:45    150
A2        1/1/15 5:45    100
A3        1/1/15 5:45    200
A1        1/1/15 6:00    200
A2        1/1/15 6:00    219
A3        1/1/15 6:00    150
A1        1/1/15 6:15    200 
...
```

Into separate `.csv` files so that each file only has the values from one cod, in doing so my output would be multiple csv files, `A1.csv`, `A2.csv`, etc. and when I open file `A1.csv` I see:

```
Code      DateTime      Value
A1        1/1/15 5:45    150
A1        1/1/15 6:00    200
A1        1/1/15 6:15    200 
...
```

and so on for all the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
for c in df.Code.unique():
    (df[df.Code == c]).to_csv(c + '.csv', index=False)

Writes these files:

Code, DateTime, Value
A1, 1/1/15 5:45,150
A1, 1/1/15 6:00,200
A1, 1/1/15 6:15,200

Etc...
```

Using groupby as proposed by @EdChum is probably faster if you have a huge data set, but I post this alternative just to show there are many ways to do things in pandas.

Comment: Thanks Steve, this was it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work, basically `groupby` on 'code' and then iterate over the groups and generate the filename and write them out:

```
In [9]:
g=df.groupby('Code')
for gp in g:
    filename = gp[0] + '.csv'
    print(filename)
    gp[1].to_csv(filename)

A1.csv
A2.csv
A3.csv
```

contents of each group:

```
In [11]:
for gp in g:
    print(gp[1])

  Code            DateTime  Value
0   A1 2015-01-01 05:45:00    150
3   A1 2015-01-01 06:00:00    200
6   A1 2015-01-01 06:15:00    200
  Code            DateTime  Value
1   A2 2015-01-01 05:45:00    100
4   A2 2015-01-01 06:00:00    219
  Code            DateTime  Value
2   A3 2015-01-01 05:45:00    200
5   A3 2015-01-01 06:00:00    150
```